# How to deploy a WAR in AWS Beanstalk with high availability

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-beanstalk

I'm using AWS Beanstalk (Tomcat) with two EC2 instances. I have minimum and maximum instances count to 2 and `Any 2` in Availability zones.

I was expecting high availability when deploying a new WAR according to Beanstalk FAQ, but when ELB resolves to a node that is in that moment deploying the WAR, a `504 Gateway Timeout` error comes up.

How can I deploy a WAR with high availability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the rolling update settings in elastic beanstalk? That way it deploys to one at a time whilst leaving the other in service